# Is the Sigmoid Function a Probability Distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

This could be a stupid question but, since sigmoid function maps values between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to values between 0 and 1, I thought it could be a probability distribution. However when I take the integral, I get

$$ x + \ln(1 + e^{-x}) $$

Little cleanup

$$ \ln e^{x} + \ln(1+e^{-x})  $$

$$ \ln (e^{x}\cdot 1 + e^{x}e^{-x})  $$

$$ \ln (1 + e^{x} )  $$

When I evaluate this for bounds $-\infty$ and $\infty$, I do not get the result 1. Did I do something wrong, and is there another form of the sigmoid function (perhaps normalized) to use it as a probability distribution?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: The sigmoid function has the properties of a _cumulative distribution function_, so if you want to obtain the corresponding density you want to differentiate it not integrate it. (Sorry, I deleted my comment by mistake).

Comment: The weird thing is, I see sigmoid being fed into maximum likelihood calculations, even though its not a pdf. Is that okay? Example - http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf

Comment: That file has $30$ pages; don't you think it would make sense to tell us which part of it you're referring to?

Comment: Very sorry - page 18.

Comment: I think you're going to have to describe more concretely where you see a problem. I see the sigmoid being used for parametrizing a probability; I don't see it being used as a distribution. Where do you see that?

Comment: I see, author uses capital $P(y=1|..)$ for which a CDF can be used. He puts the whole thing together though and uses it as a pdf $p(y | x;\theta) = (h_\theta(x))^y (1-h_\theta(x))^{1-y}$ (small $p$). Is that fine?

Comment: Maybe I was being too picky on notation; maximizing the product of parametrized probabilities does make sense for maximizing likelihood, and the author never calls $p(..)$ a pdf anyway.. I just wasnt sure if a pdf was mandatory for maximum likelihood calculation, I guess that was my real question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sigmoid

$$f(x) = 1 / (1 + e^{-x})$$

is not a probability distribution function (it approaches 0 on -∞ and 1 on +∞, so its integral will also be ∞). However it is a cumulative distribution function of [logistic distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution), if thats what you mean.

Comment: since the output is on the interval of $[0, 1]$ can the output be interpreted as a probability?

Comment: yes, by definition of CDF: f(x) is the probability that X will take a value less than or equal to x